# XChangeProperty to change icon in unity bar and alt tab menu and window of running app?

Tags: icons, x11, xorg

For X11 systems I was trying to change the icon of the application during run time. This means that the window icon should change, the icon showed in alt+tab menu, and the icon in the unity bar.

This is preview of ubuntu:
[image]

ubuntu doesnt have a window icon, but other operating systems like metacity do.

So I was thinking of using `XChangeProperty` like this:

```
unsigned int buffer[] = {16, 16, 4294901760..............., 32, 32, 0............}; //ARGB 32bit packed array

Display *d = XOpenDisplay(0);
int s = DefaultScreen(d);
Atom net_wm_icon = XInternAtom(d, "_NET_WM_ICON", False);
Atom cardinal = XInternAtom(d, "CARDINAL", False);
XEvent e;

//w == window

int length = 2 + 16 * 16 + 2 + 32 * 32;
XChangeProperty(d, w, net_wm_icon, cardinal, 32,
                 PropModeReplace, (const unsigned char*) buffer, length);


XMapWindow(d, w);
while(1) XNextEvent(d, &e);
```

I do this code in js-ctypes, but the above is C code i found during my research, will this work for running application?

Thanks

Comment: Have you actually tried it? I would expect this code to work as you expct in any ewmh-compliant wm/task switcher

Comment: I haven't tested it yet as i do it in js-ctypes which takes lots of effort, so post before making the attempt to make sure im going in right direction. Thanks for the comment man, if you think it should work then I'll start putting the effort, it usually takes me a few days, I'll report back by next weekend :)

Comment: May I ask you why js-ctypes? ( I'm author of node-x11, X11 protocol client for node.js )

Comment: @AndreySidorov Oh wow that's so cool! I appreciate you taking the time to help us out :) Reason for me though is I'm using it in a firefox addon :) With js-ctypes I dont need to import anything you can check out my x11 js-ctypes skeleton here: https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/3e31f8e5ff3130b00484 :)

Comment: just tried this example https://gist.github.com/sidorares/adc2b2d94a3485cff943 and it works for icewm but not unity, not sure why

Comment: Thanks very much for that. In what way did it not work? Like did it not change in the unity bar? but it did change in the alt+tab menu? Btw i got the code above from here: http://lists.kde.org/?l=kwin&m=115435217715650&w=2 i ran the c code and it worked fine but i havent been able to test it on a currently running app, i have to get hte ctypes set up for that, my goal is to change the icon of firefox (add a little badge to it)

Comment: Didn't work in unity (no icon update in switcher or unity launcher) but worked in icewm and metacity ( window icon, task bar and alt-tab switcher icons update dynamically - in my example, switch to next icon every 2 seconds)

Comment: looks like impossible in unity: http://askubuntu.com/questions/244949/dynamically-change-the-application-icon

Comment: also see this comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=239575#c6

Comment: Thank you man for your awesome investigation. Here is a topic on askubuntu showing how to referesh icon when its not running, interesting: http://askubuntu.com/questions/500544/how-to-refresh-launcher-icon-application-menu-in-ubuntu-12-04/500609#500609

Comment: that's looks a bit hackish (and you need to modify dynamically .desktop file) Look at https://www.npmjs.org/package/desktop-entry and https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-x11-desktop-entry if you need to parse .desktop in js

Comment: Thanks man I'll report back if i figure it out :)

Comment: Hey at @AndreySidorov on Ubuntu it seems this thing called Nautilus does the icon changing in bar just like we were expecting. I can't figure out how this was accomplished do you have any ideas? Thx

Comment: gist of working C code posted above: [GitHubGIST ::  Noitidart / _c-X11_XChangeProperty.c](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/a1541a6968d25ecaaefc)

Comment: Hey @AndreySidorov it looks like we might be able to get it to work in unity, we have to send some urgency it looks like with WM_HINT: https://github.com/benizi/config-bin/blob/4f606bde322af570429bbb17b3bd7023093cee27/set-icon.py#L66

  im still struggling to pull this off in jsctypes topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28870763/x11-xchangeproperty-net-wm-icon but can you please test by sending the WM_HINT so i can know if my effort will yiled anything :)