# Retrieve Ubuntu launcher icon

Tags: linux, x11, launcher, window-managers

Is there a way to retrieve application launcher icon.

I tried `xprop _NET_WM_ICON` command but it returns with

```
_NET_WM_ICON: Not found error.
```

But I can see the icon in System Tray(Launcher).

How can we retrieve that icon. Any other method ?

Comment: Can you attach screenshot showing which icon exactly you want to retrieve? And what is the preferred results format (path to file, icon name, binary icon data, ...)?

Comment: lets say if we launch mozilla browser. we see mozilla icon in system launcher bar. That Icon we can retrieve using xprop _NET_WM_ICON command and pointing cursor on mozilla browser window. But this approach doesnt work for many other windows.

Comment: I use neither Ubuntu nor Unity (their UI shell). I don't see your screen and I don't understand which UI element you mean by "system launcher bar". You use "System Tray" interchangeably in your question and that further confuses me. Please update your question with relevant screenshot, so people are better able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu/Unity it's defined in application .desktop file, not _NET_WM_ICON. See my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112040/dynamic-icon-ubuntu-nautilus/27116006#27116006) and [desktop file specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/)

You can associate your window with desktop file [by setting _NET_WM_DESKTOP_FILE property](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530376/association-window-desktop-file-launcher-entry/530431#530431)